# Issue while trying to render a table with django-tables2

Tags: django, render

I'm trying to follow this tutorial :

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html.

Up to point 3), everything is OK.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="full name")

person1 = Person("John Nash")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import models as m

def people(request):
   return render(request, "people.html", {"people": m.Person.objects.all()})
```

My App is called GenerateTable

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^GenerateTable/', 'GenerateTable.views.people', name='GenerateTable'),
]
```

people.html

```
{# tutorial/templates/people.html #}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL   }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
  </head>
   <body>
    {% render_table people %}
  </body>
  </html>
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
 File "C:\Users\gis\Desktop\ArcGISTools\ArcGISsite\GenerateTable\views.py",    line 6, in people
return render(request, "people.html", {"people": m.Person.objects.all()})
OperationalError: no such table: GenerateTable_person
```

I have already search for similar issues to find a solution, but with no luck yet.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Full error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py:37: RemovedInDjango110Warning:      django.core.context_processors is deprecated in favor of     django.template.context_processors.
__import__(name)

Internal Server Error: /GenerateTable/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149,      in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147,   in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gis\Desktop\ArcGISTools\ArcGISsite\GenerateTable\views.py", line 6, in people
return render(request, "people.html", {"people": m.Person.objects.all()})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 97, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 95, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 206, in render
return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 197, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 955, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py", line 129, in render
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\config.py", line 57, in configure
table.paginate(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py", line 558, in paginate
self.page = self.paginator.page(page)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 50, in page
number = self.validate_number(number)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 39, in validate_number
if number > self.num_pages:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 86, in _get_num_pages
if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 77, in _get_count
self._count = len(self.object_list)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\rows.py", line 187, in __len__
return len(self.data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\tables.py", line 56, in __len__
self.queryset.count() if hasattr(self, 'queryset') else len(self.list)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 371, in count
return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 483, in get_count
number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 464, in get_aggregation
result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 852, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in   __exit__
 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such table: GenerateTable_person
```

Analyzing Django debbuging, error seems to be generated when running the 9th line in people.html:

```
 {% render_table people %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve my problem. I had to run the following commands to create the needed tables on Django database according to my models.py

```
python manage.py makemigrations <myapp>
python manage.py migrate
```

Thanks!!